# Работа с TextView андроид

Tags: android

Есть такой лэйаут

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:onClick="onButtonClick"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button1" android:onClick="onButtonClick"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

</LinearLayout>

для кнопки написан метод

```
//...
editText1 = (EditText) this.findViewById(id.editText1);
//...
    public void onButtonClick(View v) {
    editText1.setText("http://www.rozrobka.com");
}
```

он добавлен в свойства кнопки
Вопрос: Почему при нажатии та текствью вызывается onButtonClick?
Прошу прощения если тупой вопрос, но не могу найти ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все, разобрался: каким-то образом в описание layout влезла строка

```
android:onClick="onButtonClick"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:onClick="onButtonClick" android:orientation="vertical" >
```

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Я думаю дело в том, что `onButtonClick` также навешен на LinearLayout, соответственно onclick срабатывает при клике на любой элемент в layout.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button1" android:onClick="onButtonClick"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" /> </LinearLayout>
```